# How to validate a jtextfield to accept only pakistan cnic format?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, jtextfield

I need to validate a JTextField by allowing the user to input only cnic number according to this format 12345-1234567-1, i am using this regular expression but it is not worked.
this is my function

```
private void idSearchKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String cnicValidator = idSearch.getText();

    if (cnicValidator.matches("^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$")) {
        idSearch.setEditable(true);
    }
    else {
        idSearch.setEditable(false);
    }        
}
```

kindly provide me some guidence how to validate my jtextfield...thanks

Comment: "Not working" what does it do instead of what you expect? Does it work for some inputs?

Comment: Drop the `+` from `[0-9+]`, unless you actually need to match `+`. You can also use `\d` (escaped to `\\d` in a Java string literal) to match digits.

Comment: If the user has entered a non-matching input, why would you disable `idSearch`, preventing them from changing it?

Comment: i mean when i run my project i enter digits but my else part are running not if part...kindly provide some code

Comment: Code for what, exactly?

Comment: I ran your program with this 12345-1234567-1 input and regular expression work perfectly. For this input I got true value if I changed the input value 123-45-1234567-1 the I got false.

Comment: when i ran my program with this regular expression and i started input digits but my else part are running always ...i don't know thats going on with my program

Comment: kindly provide full validate function or check @AndyTurner

Comment: Use trim function idSearch.getText() one. May be that help you to get the correct input.

Comment: `System.out.println("12345-1234567-1".matches("^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$"));` => prints true. `System.out.println("1234512345671".matches("^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$"));` => prints false.

Comment: not working at all, is there any other way to validate instead of regular expression ??

Comment: Take a look at the approach I suggested and see if it works for you. You shouldn't need to validate using it, because you're forcing the data to be in the correct format as it's entered by the users.

Comment: kindly see my question again on edited portion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution to validating post-input would be to use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) combined with a [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) to restrict the input to begin with.

The code to create one of these would be something along the lines of:

```
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final MaskFormatter mask;
        try {
            mask = new MaskFormatter("#####-#######-#");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format mask specified", e);
        }

        // You can optionally set a placeholder character by doing the following:
        mask.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        final JFormattedTextField formattedField = new JFormattedTextField(mask);

        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.add(formattedField);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The format mask `#` only accepts digits (specifically, it accepts any character where `Character.isDigit(char)` returns `true`), and forbids any non-digit from being entered.